# gcc undefined reference to `fopen_s'

Tags: c, eclipse, undefined-reference

I don't know if I can ask this question again,
There are many duplicates but none of the solutions actually worked for me

I'm using gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC)
And by trying to build I get

```
undefined reference to `fopen_s'
```

Please make your suggestions on how I can solve this issue :)
Note: I'm using Windows 7 / 64-bit

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your version of gcc is too old I believe

Comment: See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65999)

Comment: What is the question? Do you just want to know why this is happening **or** are you asking how to fix this?

Comment: @ErikW Can you tell me how to upgrade to the latest version (I'm on Win7 / 64-bit) ;) thaanks

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks I will try to upgrade my GCC installation and see what will happen

Comment: @SiggiSv Actually the Fix , I just updated the question , thanks

Comment: @TheBeast After all it is an option.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I have used mingw and cygwin and it seems the latest GCC they have is gcc 4.9 but the last version is now 7.1 :p

Comment: The functions, like `fopen_s()` are only found in MSDN (microsoft) implementations and are not actually part of the standard C libraries.

Comment: @user3629249 I agree but I just tried a friend PC and it's working fine it has gcc 4.8

Comment: what OS is your friends' PC running?  does he have `visual C++` installed?  You might want to read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features for the details

Comment: @user3629249 He has win7 64-bit with visual C++ installed, same as me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not including the file its written in. Not sure where it is but it'd be something like "#include name.h", unless its a function you wrote yourself, in which case you'll need to create a .h file and include it at the top of both this file and the file you wrote that function in, like this " #include "name.h" "

Comment: I found that the function is created by Microsoft ... Regarding the code it's a big project I just imported and tried to run .. Also I just tried in a friend PC and it's working fine it has gcc 4.8